# What does it mean to have something differ between the coefficients?

Tags: r

I need to create a model where the presence/absence of pox can differ between species
and between elevations while also allowing for the effect of elevation to differ between species.

This is what I have:

```
library(car)
library(effects)

modPox=glm(Activepox ~ Species + Elev, data = datPox, family = binomial)
summary(modPox)

Anova(modPox)

plot(allEffects(modPox))
```

However, what does it means to have pox differing between the two coefficients? What do I need to add in order to have pox differ between species and elevation? What does the effect of elevation differing between species mean?

Thank you.

This is what the data looks like:

```
    Site    Species Bandno  Date    Sex Age Oldpox  Activepox   Malaria Elev
1   AIN APAP    159174793   7/22/2004   U   H   0   0   2   mid
2   AIN APAP    159174964   7/6/2004    M   H   0   1   2   mid
3   AIN APAP    159174965   7/7/2004    F   H   0   0   2   mid
```

Data:

```
datPox <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Site = c("AIN", "AIN", "AIN"),
           Species = c("APAP", "APAP", "APAP"),
            Bandno = c(159174793L, 159174964L, 159174965L),
              Date = c("7/22/2004", "7/6/2004", "7/7/2004"),
               Sex = c("U", "M", "F"),
               Age = c("H", "H", "H"),
            Oldpox = c(0L, 0L, 0L),
         Activepox = c(0L, 1L, 0L),
           Malaria = c(2L, 2L, 2L),
              Elev = c("mid", "mid", "mid")
)
```

Comment: You probably want to add the interaction terms, try `Activepox ~ Species*Elev`. Also see `help('formula')`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!!